# Unable to fix crash/exception reported by iTunes review team

Tags: ios, objective-c

I recently submitted an update to an app that is current live on the app store. Nothing was changed other than adding some new content to a plist and switching from revmob to admob. The itunes team sent me this crash report which I have symbolicated.

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x333533e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b04e95e objc_exception_throw + 26
2   UIKit                           0x354ee61c +[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:] + 436
3   UIKit                           0x35330fae -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 38
4   UIKit                           0x351ba784 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 524
5   UIKit                           0x35162d1a -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1006
6   UIKit                           0x351627a8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
7   UIKit                           0x351621ea _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6194
8   GraphicsServices                0x36e7a5f2 _PurpleEventCallback + 586
9   CoreFoundation                  0x333288f2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 10
10  CoreFoundation                  0x33328158 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
11  CoreFoundation                  0x33326f2a __CFRunLoopRun + 642
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3329a238 0x33291000 + 37432
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3329a0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
14  UIKit                           0x351b9468 0x3515f000 + 369768
15  UIKit                           0x351b62b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
```

How can I attempt to fix this problem which seems to do with initing the storyboard? I have tried clean installs on simulator and my test device (iPad) but I am unable to reproduce the crash.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806122/ios-app-crashes-for-apple-review-team-but-not-on-my-device