# Xcode 5.0.2 doesn't point to the actual crashed line

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm using Xcode 5.0.2 and it crashes when i run the iPhone app on the device but the problem is that it doesn't point me to the actual line that crashed and doesn't print any thing from the stack trace in the console, it only point me to main in this line:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

however i tried the following:

- put an exception point for all exceptions
- surround the line stated above with a try catch block in order to print the stack trace but it doesn't print anything as well
- put a break point inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method but it also doesn't stop at these position

here's an image for all the threads that's generated when it stops inside main:
[image]

i think that there's something wrong with the storyBoard but i don't know exactly what it is, thanks in advance

Comment: did you enable NSZombie

Comment: check your storyboard name

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS app crashes for apple review team but not on my device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806122/ios-app-crashes-for-apple-review-team-but-not-on-my-device)

Answer (score 7):

1. Go to Project Navigator
2. Select Break Point Tab
3. Tap '+' buttom from bottom
4. Add Exception Breakpoint

After adding this.. it will point line which is crashing app.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably a dead reference. E.g. a connection from a view to an instance variable that is no longer there.

Check all Outlets in your Storyboard. One will have an exclamationmark next to it.

Comment: i traced all the views on my storyBoard and there isn't any isolated one !!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't catching the exception that is being thrown you need to add an [Exception Breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) which will catch the crash and stop on that line.

> Add an exception breakpoint to your project in the breakpoint navigator.
>
> **Steps**
>
> 1. In the bottom-left corner of the breakpoints navigator, click the Add button.
> 2. Choose Add Exception Breakpoint.
> 3. In the Exception pop-up menu, choose the type of exception on which you want execution to stop:
>
>    - All. Stops on all exceptions.
>    - Objective-C. Stops on Objective-C exceptions.
>    - C++. Stops on C++ exceptions.
>
> To stop on a particular C++ exception, specify the exception name.
>
> 4 Choose the phase of the exception handling process at which you want program execution to stop.
>
> 5 Click Done.

[image]

Comment: @Downvoter please detail the reason for the downvote. Leaving a reason will allow user to improve answer if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check your storyboard name is valid or not. this answer is my guessing

because the Storyboard is the problem image will describes

Enable NSZombie objects in your project. goTo edit schema and than enable

[image]